# How do I include non-java files in jar compilation using maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a folder with .txt files that hold data. This data is loaded into my game and is then used in the game.

I also have 3 other libraries that are not on maven. So I loaded them into the .m2 folder using this plugin: maven-install-plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install-everythingrs-api-jar</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>everythingrs-api</groupId>
                    <artifactId>everythingrs-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <file>${project.basedir}/lib/everythingrs-api.jar</file>
                    <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                ...
            </execution>
            <execution>
                ...
            </execution>
        <executions>
    </plugin>
```

And then I am using this plugin: maven-assembly-plugin to compile the project into a jar with the libraries inside of it.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>${main-class-path}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Now, this if i run mvn clean validate install, will copy the 3 libraries i have into .m2, then the second plugin will compile into an executable jar containing the libraries imported from maven repo and the 3 libraries that were added to the .m2 into the jar.

However, i also have a folder which is in the project ./ but outside of the src, how can i make the maven plugins also include this directory/folder into the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [maven resources plugin.](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)  It allows you to add a folder that's not under `/src/main/resources` as a maven resource.